# AJAX post request with webapp2

Tags: python, ajax, json, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm working with GAE/webapp2 and currently using request.POST to pull in JSON data coming from an AJAX post. It comes across as a UnicodeMultiDict.

Is there a better approach than request.POST.  What is a good way to read this in if I desire to recapture the data structure that was on the client side?  Ideally, I'd like to minimize the reconstruction work and preserve integers, Booleans, object structure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

GAE is a PaaS therefore stuffs like RMI (or its equivalent in python) currently do not exist.  I'm currently using a custom markup language in order to preserve basic datatypes and to help the parser in validating the data. It is a simple key-value structure formed as follows:

```
"key/subkey1/.../subkeyn":(<datatype>)"value";
```

the parser reads the key, the value and the datatype and creates a hierarchical tructure of nested objects that replicates the hierarchy in the response(the aim is to have a symple access to the object "key/.../subkeyn" by requesting obj_key.obj_1....obj_n in the hierarchy of generated objects). The datatype is used to validate and characterize that data during the creation of the object structure

This can be extended further. For instance (I'm talking in Java terms, sorry) I can create an interface "Sendable" that have all the methods necessary to A) put the object in serial and sendable form, B) to reconstruct the object from a response. Then any object implementing Sendable will be able to be sent via that protocol and reconstructed.
For example  imagine that the interface Sendable is defined as below (in pseudocode):

```
interface Sendable{
   string toSendableString();
   void fromSendable(Object hierarchy);
}
```

and imagine to have a class User (in pseudocode)

```
class User implements Sendable{
   string username;
   string hash;
   string toSendableString(){
      return "\"user/username\":(string)\"" + username + "\";"
             + "\"user/hash\":(hash)\"" + hash + "\"";
   }
   void fromSendable(Object h){
      username = h.getvalue("username");
      hash = h.getvalue("hash");
   }
}
```

Then in the datatype you can specify the type User and any time the parser find an User datatype can check whether it is a valid type, if it implements Sendable and then create an object by calling the dedicated function.  (Clearly it must pass to that function only the sub-hierarchy that contains the object).